# SSL and Redirect Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

so I've been trying to setup my wordpress site with a SSL Certificate. The Certificate has been bought and installed properly. However I'm currently having issues with the redirects.

At this point I have edited my .htaccess to include:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I also included this into the wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Further I've replaced all instances of

```
http:// example.com to https:// example.com

http:// www.example.com to https:// example.com
```

with the help of the tool "Database search and replace".

So in the WP Dashboard under General the site is set to https://...

Browsing through all the Guides online available this should be everything that is necessary. Cloudflare has been paused to not interfere with anything.

The problem lies within the redirects after checking with redirect-checker.org:

https:// example.com 200 Redirects none Okay

https:// example.com/test/ 200 Redirects none Okay

https:// example.com/wp-admin/ 302 ➝ 200 Redirects 1

("Why is here a 302 being used? Shouldn't it only be 200?")

http:// example.com 301 ➝ 200 Redirects 1

("While this looks fine it's giving me the message: You use 301 and 302 redirect at the same time. This might be confusing for search engine. Generally, please do not use 301 and 302 redirects at the same time.")

http:// example.com/test/ 200 Redirects none Okay

("Shouldn't be okay, since it should redirect to the https:// version")

http:// example.com/wp-admin/ 301 ➝ 302 ➝ 200 Redirects 2

("Gives me the message: You use 301 and 302 redirect at the same time. This might be confusing for search engine. Generally, please do not use 301 and 302 redirects at the same time." and "You use a 302 redirect.")

It seems that somehow there is a 302 enabled somewhere where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Well, where is `https://example.com/wp-admin/` redirecting you? If it's not obvious in a browser, try `curl`.

Comment: It redirects to `https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` with a 302 redirect

Comment: I don't know why WordPress needs to do that but why do you consider it to be a problem?

Comment: The Problem is actually not this one link. Even though it should be a 301 for various purposes. Further it's only slowing down the site load.
As you can see other links such as `http:// example.com/test/` are not being redirected to the https version